# VX works simulator with Opengl SC

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vxworks, safety-critical, opengl-sc

Is there any VXworks simulator available where i can build my Opengl ES or SC application and run it? I'm new to opengl plateform, My project involves Development of display for safety critical system. I want to simulate a basic opengl sc code on VXworks. My Target Embedded plateform is not yet decided. Any guidance or suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I've had no problem running SC and ES on Linux (part from the usual Linux-configuration-hell and broken Mesa sw-renderers). What is your exact problem?

Comment: My project involves software development for safety critical systems. Hence I would prefer to use a real time operating system like Vxwork  rather than general purpose operating system Linux.

Comment: I've done OpenGL SC for LynxOS and Vxworks RTOS. A main difference from an RTOS OpenGL are buggy and slow drivers because A: few use them, B: known bugs and performance issues are more often avoided by end users rather than fixed by vendor. This can't be simulated; you need the target platform. A second difference is missing memory deallocation, as it would introduce memory fragmentation. This is often managed by vendor specific extensions; no chance of simulation. A third difference is threading and interrupts often being less supported, often leading to a single context.

Comment: My advice: assume there is single context, no memory deallocation, lots of bugs, and poor performance. Happy hunting.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for your reply. Can i know what was the architecture of target you implemented your opengl application and version of VXworks you have used?

Comment: No. If you have specific technical questions ask away at SO and maybe I'll look into it on my spare time. If you need more support try find me and make an offer I can't refuse ;-)